# How to backup nginx current data on memory or share memory?

Tags: nginx

I am current implement nginx module with involving share memory, I'm wondering whether it backup the nginx shared memory to somewhere in the machine?

Ref: https://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide-advanced.html#shm-creating